# ietd - spamming logs ietd: unable to connect (Connection refused) 2

Tags: debian, iscsi, open-iscsi

I have a fileserver (debian wheezy, 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux) set up with open-iscsi, o2cb, ocfs2. 3 connected clients and the fileserver itself are working great, serving the share to all connected hosts.

BUT: I am messing around for days now, to find out what is causing the logs (syslog, daemon.log) to get flooded with the following message every 30seconds:

```
Dec 10 16:39:37 fileserver ietd: unable to connect (Connection refused) 2!
Dec 10 16:40:07 fileserver ietd: unable to connect (Connection refused) 2!
Dec 10 16:40:37 fileserver ietd: unable to connect (Connection refused) 2!
```

I tried to get debug information from ietd, but nothing to work with, as the log lines keep being the same.

/etc/iet/ietd.conf:

```
iSNSServer 10.31.116.20
Target iqn.2001-04.com.example:storage.disk2.sys1.xyz
    IncomingUser xxUSERxx xxPASSxx
    OutgoingUser
    Lun 0 Path=/dev/md1,Type=fileio
    Alias LUN1
```

Any hints or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Yours Jens